# validating a numeric input's length in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

**foo.blade.php**

```
<input type="text" name="national-id" />
```

**FooController.php**

```
$rules = [
    'national-id' => 'required|size:10|numeric'
];
```

the `national-id` field should contain `10` `digits` and I actually expected the code above to validate this , but instead It will check If the `national-id` exactly equals to 10 or not ...
how can I validate the `length` of a numeric field?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

In fact you don't need to use `digits_between` rule. You can use [digits rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-digits) so according to documentation it will be enough to use:

```
$rules = [
    'national-id' => 'required|digits:10'
];
```

without `numeric` rule because `digits` rule also verify if given value is numeric.

Comment: sidenote: `digits:10` means: "must be exactly 10 digits" (not less not more)

Answer (score 56):

When using size on a number it will check if the number is equal to the size, on string, it will check the amount of characters, for number you should use :

```
'number' => 'required|numeric|digits_between:1,10'
```

Comment: you don't need to use numeric

Comment: @yatabani why not?! add more content so the awnser could be more complete. Thanks

Comment: Please note, that if your number contains fractional part it will be automatically invalidated, you can use only integers

Answer (score 17):

In laravel the size validation on a field that's numeric  will indicate the max integer it cannot be larger than.

Use digits_between:

```
   'national-id' => 'required|digits_between:10,10|numeric'
```

Comment: Is It the only way? I thought there must be rule like `length` or etc to figure this out

Comment: work's well but when the user enter's a wrong value , the error Is this (The national-id must be between 10 and 10 digits)!

Comment: you don't need to use numeric